# ORA-00933 when running procedure in ODI 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am creating a one-time procedure to update a newly added column in a target table from an existing source.  I created the update statement, tested it in SQLDeveloper, and confirmed it does exactly what I want.  However, when I add this code into a procedure task, it is giving me an ORA-00933 (SQL Command not properly ended) error.  I attached the sql statement in question along with some explanation of the options I am picking.

Already done:

- New column added to table on database
- Model for target table updated
- Mapping updated
- Initial load verified to have correct results in new column
- Journal load verified to have correct results in new column

Tried (no difference):

- Adding and removing semicolon (;)
- Simplifying query to remove "WHERE EXISTS" clause

Target Command:

```sql
UPDATE <%=odiRef.getSchemaName( "TARGET_SCHEMA", "D")%>.TARGET_TABLE target
   SET NEW_COLUMN = (SELECT source.EXISTING_COLUMN
                         FROM <%=odiRef.getSchemaName( "SOURCE_SCHEMA", "D")%>.SOURCE_TABLE source
                        WHERE target.SOURCE_KEY = source.PRIM_KEY)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM <%=odiRef.getSchemaName( "SOURCE_SCHEMA", "D")%>.SOURCE_TABLE source
     WHERE target.SOURCE_KEY = source.PRIM_KEY)
```

Target Command Settings:

Technology:  Oracle
Transaction Isolation:  No Change
Context:  Execution Context
Logical Schema:  TARGET_SCHEMA
Transaction:  Autocommit
Commit:  Undefined

Error message:

```
ODI-1217: Session POPULATE_TARGET_TABLE_NEW_FLAG (123456789) fails with return code 933.
ODI-1226: Step Populate_target_table_new_flag fails after 1 attempt(s).
ODI-1232: Procedure Populate_target_table_new_flag execution fails.
ODI-1228: Task Procedure-Populate_target_table_new_flag-Populate target table with New Flag fails on the target connection SOURCE_SCHEMA.
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:495)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1055)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:624)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:253)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:214)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:38)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:891)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1835)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1790)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:301)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLCommand.execute(SQLCommand.java:208)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLExecutor.execute(SQLExecutor.java:142)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLExecutor.execute(SQLExecutor.java:28)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:52)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.processTask(SessionTask.java:216)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.doExecuteTask(SessionTask.java:127)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.AbstractSessionTask.execute(AbstractSessionTask.java:886)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor$SerialTrain.runTasks(SessionExecutor.java:2225)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor.executeSession(SessionExecutor.java:610)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:718)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:611)
    at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:203)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.doProcessStartAgentTask(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:800)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartScenRequestProcessor.access$2700(StartScenRequestProcessor.java:85)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartScenRequestProcessor$StartScenTask.doExecute(StartScenRequestProcessor.java:917)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:180)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 331, Sql = UPDATE TARGET_TABLE target 
SET NEW_COLUMN = (SELECT source.EXISTING_COLUMN
FROM SOURCE_SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE source 
WHERE target.SOURCE_KEY = source.PRIM_KEY) 
 WHERE EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 
  FROM SOURCE_SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE source 
 WHERE target.SOURCE_KEY = source.PRIM_KEY);, OriginalSql = UPDATE 
TARGET_TABLE target 
SET NEW_COLUMN = (SELECT source.EXISTING_COLUMN
                     FROM SOURCE_SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE source 
                    WHERE target.SOURCE_KEY = source.PRIM_KEY) 
 WHERE EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1 
  FROM SOURCE_SCHEMA.SOURCE_TABLE source 
     WHERE target.SOURCE_KEY = source.PRIM_KEY);, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:499)
... 30 more
```

Comment: The SQL statement in log *contains semicolon* which I suppose **is the problem**, try to get rid of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue wasn't **exactly** the code itself, but it was the fact that I was not regenerating my scenario in-between code changes.  My own fault, I am mostly self taught in ODI and didn't think to try that...

Thanks to Marmite Bomber, your comment is what made me look into the problem more and realize the "generated" code wasn't updated any time I made a change.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are invalid characters in the posted code that I expect are supposed to be replaced by the target table owner and table_name in the code passed to Oracle for execution, I suspect the generated SQL is not correct.  Is there anyway you can capture the code being passed to Oracle?

Comment: The error message does include the generated SQL (which does work when put into SQL Developer.  It is worth noting that the "TARGET_SCHEMA" is ignored, but I would assume that is because it is covered by the Logical Schema so ODI is handling that with an alter session (and if it wasn't I would expect a different error).  Error message is too long for comment, will update the original question with it.